# The exact difference between A1 and A2 milk

Tags: side-effects, diabetes, proteins, milk, type-1-diabetes

up vote
0
down vote
favorite
I am no expert in biology or chemistry. There are two links one stating A1 milk is good and A2 is bad the other link claiming the opposite. Which one can I trust? What about buffalo milk which is not discussed in these links?

link1: https://authoritynutrition.com/a1-vs-a2-milk/

link2: http://food.ndtv.com/food-drinks/a1-versus-a2-milk-does-it-matter-1414225

I have no idea about the reputation of journals mentioned in link1.

Help me out.

Comment: Look at the impact factor for the journals in question.